# How to create database connection in Http Request Sampler in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I am new to JMeter. I want to make MySQL connection to database so I can calculate the time that took to upload an audio and it is inserted in the database. I am trying to upload audio to my API and when the audio uploads then it go for background processing and then it is inserted in database. I am doing load testing when I hit this API it returns success when it go for background processing. But I want to calculate time taken by when I upload audio and it is inserted in database. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it as follows:

- [Transaction Controller](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller) - to measure time of all nested samplers

  - [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) to upload file
  - [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) to loop until postprocessing is finished

    - [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) - to check your mysql database

Answer (score 0):

When the upload completes, insert a record for the given content with current time. Then Pass this new record's ID to the background job so when processing is finished it can update the same record and insert current time again. Here you go, compare the 2 times...

Comment: I am asking is there any way to create a database connection in http request sampler. So i can retrieve record from database according to parameter entered to check whether that particular record is present or not..

Comment: This was answer for "But i want to calculate time taken by when i upload audio and it is inserted in database".

Comment: Otherwise, I don't think it's possible, but why not make a "checker" script so you can just call a URL like /checkupload?id=xyz and in that script you connect to the db and verify details.